Trying to switch between frames in tkinter
I'm trying to design a (semi) text-based game in tkinter. I'd like to be able to switch between frames, with each frame acting as a menu or map. However, each button in each frame is present from the start, and transitioning from e.g. Opening to NewGame doesn't make the buttons in Opening go away.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, simpledialog

LARGE_FONT = "Verdana"

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("640x480")

class intothesea(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(root, height="640", width="480")

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Opening, NewGame, LithHarbor):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            frame.pack()

        self.show_frame(Opening)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        tk.Frame.lower(self)
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Opening(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="In. To. The. Sea.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="NEW GAME",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(NewGame))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="CONTINUE",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(LithHarbor))
        button2.pack()

class NewGame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(root, text="In. To. The. Sea.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        new_character = []

        def accept_string():
            # Prompt the user to input a string
            user_input = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Enter a string:")

            # Print the string to the console
            if user_input:
                new_character.extend(user_input)
                print(user_input)
                name.pack_forget()

        name = tk.Button(self, text="WHAT IS YOUR NAME?", command=accept_string)
        name.pack()


class LithHarbor(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="In. To. The. Sea.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


app = intothesea()
app.mainloop()



This can't be run as-written; it hits a _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!frame which already has slaves managed by pack error because you're using both grid and pack at lines 29/30 (removing frame.pack() will fix that). Also, unrelated, you don't need to (and shouldn't) use both import tkinter as tk and from tkinter import *. It's best to just use import tkinter as tk and then prefix things appropriately (e.g. tk.Tk, tk.Button etc.). From what I can see, you can just remove from tkinter import * without causing any issues!

Also, having your main class intothesea inherit from tk.Tk in addition to using root = tk.Tk() means you're technically running two instances of tkinter. Unfortunately that's just the tip of the iceberg...there are a few other issues with inheritance and how you're using pack and grid

It seems like you tried following this Answer. Make sure you understand the logic behind it or at least try to copy the syntax consistently. However, if your main question does not concern switching windows, but how your buttons are visible on the page at all times, this is a question of what is assigned to your main window and what is assigned to the subordinate views! In this case, please clarify which buttons should always be displayed and which should only be displayed when the corresponding view is called up.

There are few issues in your code:

Multiple instances of Tk().  Remove instance root.
Use root directly as the parent of container inside class intothesea.  Use self as the parent instead.
call frame.pack() after frame.grid(...) inside intothesea.__init__() which causes exception.  Remove frame.pack().
Call tk.Frame.lower(self) inside show_frame().  It is not necessary.
Use root directly as the parent of label inside class NewGame.  Use self as the parent instead.

Updated code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, simpledialog

LARGE_FONT = "Verdana"

# removed creating root

class intothesea(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("640x480")

        container = tk.Frame(self)  # removed width and height options
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Opening, NewGame, LithHarbor):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            # removed calling frame.pack()

        self.show_frame(Opening)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        # removed calling tk.Frame.lower(self)
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Opening(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="In. To. The. Sea.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="NEW GAME",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(NewGame))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="CONTINUE",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(LithHarbor))
        button2.pack()

class NewGame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="In. To. The. Sea.", font=LARGE_FONT) # used self as parent
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        new_character = []

        def accept_string():
            # Prompt the user to input a string
            user_input = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Enter a string:")

            # Print the string to the console
            if user_input:
                new_character.extend(user_input)
                print(user_input)
                name.pack_forget()

        name = tk.Button(self, text="WHAT IS YOUR NAME?", command=accept_string)
        name.pack()


class LithHarbor(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="In. To. The. Sea.", font=LARGE_FONT) # used self as parent
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


app = intothesea()
app.mainloop()


Regarding your last bullet point: Presumably his use of root as master in the NewGame and LithHarbor classes was an attempt to ensure that the header is always visible. Kind of an unhealthy mix of a header label at root level but duplicated in the alternating views...

If OP wants a common header, OP should create it inside class intothesea.

Absolutely, just trying to figure out why he altered the code when following this answer. Also this part of his question made me wonder: However, each button in each frame is present from the start, and transitioning from e.g. Opening to NewGame doesn't make the buttons in Opening go away

As already mentioned by JRiggles in the comments and acw1668 in his answer you mixed up the pack() and grid() managers. You should only use one exclusively per 'level'. Also you are not consequent in your logic of the view frames using somtimes the frame itself as its widgets master and in NewGame suddenly the parent. Also there are multiple instanciations of the Tk class.
Regarding your question of how to prevent Buttons from disappearing when changing views: just assign them to the root as master but do so in your controller class. I Implemented a 'back' button for your views NewGame and LithHarbor.
I wanted to present a version relying sole on the pack() manager since it seems sufficient for your cause and is a little easier to handle:
import tkinter as tk  # also importing 'from tkinter import *' is redundant
from tkinter import simpledialog


LARGE_FONT = "Verdana"


class InToTheSea(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # this replaces 'root = tk.Tk()' by self. Otherwise you have multiple instances
        self.geometry("640x480")

        # Button to always return to the Opening view (not visible in opening) → belongs to root/self, not the views!
        self.back_btn = tk.Button(self, text='back', command=lambda: self.show_frame(Opening))
        self.back_btn.pack()

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        # since there are no other widgets on this level fill='both' makes it the same size as root,
        # so no width and height necessary
        container.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.frames = {}
        self.current_frame = None

        # just forget grid and use pack() and pack_forget() since you seem used to it

        # maybe store the input here to pass it easier into the other views?!
        self.characters = []

        for F in (Opening, NewGame, LithHarbor):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            # don't pack here but in show_frame

        self.show_frame(Opening)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        """If currently a Frame is displayed, forget it and pack the passed one"""
        if self.current_frame is not None:
            self.current_frame.pack_forget()
        if cont == Opening:
            self.back_btn.pack_forget()
        else:
            self.back_btn.pack()
        self.current_frame = self.frames[cont]
        self.current_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


class Opening(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="In. To. The. Sea.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        # maybe think of mor describing variable names like those:
        new_btn = tk.Button(self, text="NEW GAME", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(NewGame))
        new_btn.pack()

        cont_btn = tk.Button(self, text="CONTINUE", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(LithHarbor))
        cont_btn.pack()


class NewGame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.cont = controller
        # don't switch up your logic here! master should be the class instance → self   not the parent
        label = tk.Label(self, text="In. To. The. Sea.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        def accept_string():
            # Prompt the user to input a string
            user_input = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "Enter a string:")

            # Print the string to the console
            if user_input:
                self.cont.characters.extend(user_input)
                print(user_input)
                name.pack_forget()  # you know pack_forget() so maybe stick to it
                # added this to show how the input can be passed by the "controller" class
                self.cont.frames[LithHarbor].update_char()
                self.cont.show_frame(LithHarbor)

        name = tk.Button(self, text="WHAT IS YOUR NAME?", command=accept_string)
        name.pack()


class LithHarbor(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.cont = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="In. To. The. Sea.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        # added a new label to display the characters
        self.usr_lbl = tk.Label(self, text='')
        self.usr_lbl.pack()

    def update_char(self):
        if len(self.cont.characters):
            self.usr_lbl.configure(text=self.cont.characters)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = InToTheSea()
    app.mainloop()


